# How can I switch back to the mobile version of chat?

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

I can't upload images from the mobile version of StackExchange chat rooms.  I switched to the "full site" to upload an image.

How can I get back to the mobile version?

Comment: Did you try turning it off and then back on? (And by that I mean closing the tab/opening a new tab)

Comment: Everything short of rebooted entire device has been tried.

Comment: Try switching to landscape mode and zooming out.

Comment: I rather read 1/3 of 3 lines than 2/3 of 2 lines.

Comment: Get the ChatSEy app. Then you can be the first to star things :)

Comment: You could also manually click the link from script in the url. `javascript:$('.mobile-on').click();`

Comment: No @nhgrif. Often you can see the link back to mobile if you go into landscope mode and zoom out. It's there, the css is just all jacked up on mobile.

Comment: @nhgrif You'd rather see one line than 1.5 lines? Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go back to [the full room list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), then scroll to the bottom. There's a link:

[image: mobile link]

Comment: Going to the full room list is an excess step btw. Everywhere in the chat there is such a link in the footer.

Comment: @nicael after this answer, I did see the mobile link elsewhere, but the page Shog9 refers to was the only one where I could actually tap it.