# Unsatisfying user experience of the new mobile UI on desktop computer

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

The problem: recently the UI for the Stack Exchange chat switched to mobile even in my browser on the notebook. While the UI might work fine for tablets and phones, it has some serious drawbacks on conventional systems, namely on computer w/o touchscreen and conventional keyboard.

Likewise, I was unable to find a configuration option to keep using the old style of the chat, which had tons of advantages on a traditional computer, like users, and favorite messages in the sidebar etc.

The most annoying part is that the new UI forces me to use the mouse to click "send" on every message, because hitting "Enter" only adds a \n to the multiline input field.

Is there any possibility to keep using the old chat (which I greatly preferred on the notebook) or at least a configuration option that enables "send on enter" in the mobile UI?

Comment: Can't you switch back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245650/how-can-i-switch-back-to-the-mobile-version-of-chat ? I mean it is strange that it decided to go to mobile but at least you would have something back like it was before

Comment: Mi issue is the reverse, the question you linked to is about switching back from the full version to the mobile version, but it gave me the idea to try out "full site" on the mobile ui, which brought me back to the original UI. I used to think that "full site" referred to an overview of all chats, my bad, but thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2):

I just discoverd with the inspiration of a comment that the button "Full Site" in the mobile chat leads back to the traditional view of the room you are in. Would not have guessed that from the title, still, it solved my problem.